# Symfony4 : Entity objects and controllers - @ParamConverter annotation Error in controller function

Tags: symfony4

this is my first post on Stackoverflow.
My question concerns Symfony4 Framework.

On my project I would have liked to retrieve some csv file from a controller.
However I faced an issue that I have not understood.

But let's see what I have done before this.

1. I created my project: `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton dash`
2. I created an Entity with : `php bin/console make:entity` => BnkAccountOperation
3. Once fields settled, I have migrated with : `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`
4. Then I created my CRUD model : `php bin/console make:crud`

Everything so far so good from here. Views and form works, but I would like to retrieve my data with csv file.

I built the following function in **BnkAccountOperationController** (I know there is simplier, better and more generic ways but that's good for the moment):

---

### The code

Controller - **BnkAccountOperationController.php** head of file:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\BnkAccountOperation;
use App\Form\BnkAccountOperationType;
use App\Repository\BnkAccountOperationRepository;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
* @Route("/bnk/account/operation")
*/
class BnkAccountOperationController extends Controller
{
```

controller function - **exportcsv()** :

```php
/**
*
* @Route("/raw.csv")
*/
public function exportcsv()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(BnkAccountOperation::class);
    $operations = $repository->findAll();

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($operations as $operation) 
    {
        $data = array(
            $operation->getOpDate()->format('d-m-Y'), 
            $operation->getOpType(), 
            $operation->getOpCategory(),
            $operation->getOpLabel(),
            $operation->getOpValue()
        );
        $rows[] = implode(',', $data);
    }

    $content  = implode("\n", $rows);
    $response = new Response($content);
    $filename = "raw.csv";
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.$filename);

    return $response;
}
```

There are also 5 generated CRUD functions from the comand typed earlier:

1. `function index(BnkAccountOperationRepository $bnkAccountOperationRepository): Response`
2. `public function new(Request $request): Response`
3. `public function show(BnkAccountOperation $bnkAccountOperation): Response`
4. `public function edit(Request $request, BnkAccountOperation $bnkAccountOperation): Response`
5. `public function delete(Request $request, BnkAccountOperation $bnkAccountOperation): Response`

---

### My issue

So if I put my `exportcsv()` function right after the 5th function I will blast me this error:

- [object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CywlO.png)
- [detailed error on log tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpS4q.png)

Here are config informations of the project :

- [php bin/console debug:router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAjJ4.png)
- config/services.yaml *# I never wrote anything here: autogenerated*

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false 
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

- The content of my **/src** folder in the project

  ```
  .
  ├── Controller
  │   ├── BnkAccountOperationController.php
  ├── Entity
  │   └── BnkAccountOperation.php
  ├── Form
  │   └── BnkAccountOperationType.php
  ├── Kernel.php
  ├── Migrations
  │   └── Version20180409113840.php
  ├── Repository
  │   └── BnkAccountOperationRepository.php
  └── Utils
  ```

---

### The workaround I found

I made some searches over the web and found that **I have to put my function over the first one** (the index function).
By doing this it works. I can retrieve my csv file.

- [csvfile download popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkVFp.png)

But I still do not understand why it can't works as my function is the last declared on the controller.

---

### My questions

1. It is related with a path configuration issue ?
2. How this annotation error can be avoided (i.e: if I add another function as importcsv) ? I saw it is unmaintained on [Symfony version4 - ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)
3. Should I create a class under my Util folder to put this kind of job and just do the routing with my controller?

Any help to understand this is much appreciated.